# Are dua's without action accepted by Allah?

Tags: dua, tawakkul

There is a hadith relating to the Prophet and a Bedouin.

> One day Prophet Muhammad ( peace and blessings be upon him) noticed a Bedouin leaving his camel without tying it.
>   He asked the Bedouin - Why don't you tie down your camel?
>   The Bedouin answered - I put my trust in Allah.
>   The Prophet ( peace and blessings be upon him)  then said - Tie your camel first, then put your trust in Allah

([Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/727020))

---

Does this mean it's the same for Dua's?  If I make a dua to Allah and ask for example:

> Please give me health.

But don't bother taking `action` to exercise, and eat healthy nutritious foods.  Is this a similar scenario as above?  i.e. do everything you can first, and then put your trust in Allah?

Or, is it enough to get healthy by eating badly, with zero exercise and just doing dua to become healthy?

Comment: This is actually a really good question. Any source to which I can find that story?

Comment: The best I can do is give you this link: http://www.islamhelpline.com/node/7905.  In this link it says that this hadith is indeed related by at-Tirmidhi, and the scholars and jurists in Islam are unanimous that the above quoted hadith meets the criteria and requirements of al-Bukhari and Muslim and is declared as authentic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole hadeeth revolves around the concept called *"Tawakkul"* (i.e. putting one's trust on Allah alone).

However, there is permissible and impermissible form of Tawakkul. And we learn the permissible form of tawakkul from the Messenger of Allah (salallahu alayhi wassalam). One of his names is the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) is al-Mutawakkil (One who depends only on Allah). The Permanent committee of Scholarly Research and Ifta' said:

> " We should have Tawakkul to follow the way of Allah's Messenger
>   (peace be upon him) in this regard as he was the best person who had
>   Tawakkul. **He used to consider other appropriate material means along
>   with his Tawakkul.So, whoever ignores the material means thinking that
>   it is sufficient for them to have Tawakkul, contradict the way of
>   Allah's Messenger (peace be upon him). This type of Tawakkul is not
>   permissible. Rather, it is recklessness and not a Shary (Islamically
>   lawful) Tawakkul.**"

Shaykh al Fawzaan comments in his explanation of al Usool uth Thalaathah:

> And we should know that tawakkul does not negate using the means (to
>   achieve a goal). So the Muslim combines having tawakkul upon Allaah and
>   utilising the means. However you do not place your tawakkul upon the
>   means; rather you depend upon Allaah.

Shaykh al Fawzaan comments in his explanation of al Usool uth Thalaathah:

> So you plant the seed in the earth; this is the means. **However you do
>   not depend upon your planting and your own action. Rather you have
>   reliance upon Allaah with regard to the growth of this plant and its
>   producing fruit and its being kept safe and its being good and
>   suitable.**

So, the advice is you should combine both i.e. do the action that is required and then put the trust in Allah. In your example, **Action + Du'a**. However, you do not put your trust on your action or the means. Rather, you put your trust on Allah. That is the right way of **Tawakkul**.

**Source**: [The Meaning of Tawakkul](http://abdurrahman.org/character/the-meaning-of-tawakkul.html),

[Tawakkul and Tawkeel](http://abdurrahman.org/character/tawkeel-tawakkul.html)

Comment: Please let me know if I have understood correctly.  Tawakkul (trusting in Allah) includes you taking action, i.e. taking whatever action/means you need to achieve something, but not thinking you are the means, but making sure you realise that Allah is the means?

Comment: @oshirowanen Exactly. All sources of sustenance, every guidance and every success come from Allah.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you must get drug and eat nutritious foods because must taking reasons

At the [IslamQA website they wrote](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/11749)

> Taking the appropriate means does not affect belief in al-qadar; in
>   fact it is part of perfecting that belief. Allaah decrees things for
>   us, and He wants things from us. What He decrees for us is hidden from
>   us, but what He wants from us, He commands us to do. He wants us to
>   convey the call to the kuffaar even if He knows that they will not
>   believe. He wants us to fight them even if He knows that we will be
>   defeated by them.
>
> It is this confusion about what Allaah wants for us and what He wants
>   from us that has led to the confusion about this matter and caused us
>   to fall into haraam things.

And when Allah said:

> وَهُزِّي إِلَيْكِ بِجِذْعِ النَّخْلَةِ تُسَاقِطْ عَلَيْكِ رُطَبًا
>   جَنِيًّا ﴿مريم: ٢٥﴾
>
> And shake toward you the trunk of the palm tree; it will drop upon you
>   ripe, fresh dates.

Allah can drop dates without shaking the palm tree but Allah want as to take reasons

> It is true that Allaah is the One Who does whatever He wants, He is
>   the Creator of all things, the One in Whose hand is the sovereignty of
>   all things, the One to Whom belong the keys of the heavens and the
>   earth, but He has created laws according to which this universe
>   operates, although He is Able to go beyond these laws but He does not
>   do this for everyone.