# Are curses the exact opposite of dua's?

Tags: dua, lanat

Are curses the exact opposite of dua's?

I understand from the last question I asked titled "[Dua with or without action](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/dua-with-or-without-action)" that dua's need to be followed by action, i.e. if your dua is for health and you just sit on your behind eating lots of food, you're not going to become healthy; the dua for health needs to be followed up by healthy eating and exercise.

Are curses the same?  As in for example, if you're in a poor country, where people are begging for money, for example your neighbour, and you don't have any money to give them, but they think you are loaded, if they curse you, will you be cursed, or will the curser have to follow up the curse with action?  For example, lets say this people's curse is that you experience hardship in the form of a disability.  Is that all the person has to do, or will that person have to do the curse and follow it up with actions to cause you to become disabled, like placing items infront of you deliberately so you trip over them and break a bone?

So basically, I just wanted to know if dua's and curses are the same interms of making the dua or curse and then having to follow up the dua/curse with action, then trusting in Allah?  Or is it enough to curse someone, without following it up with action, and trusting in Allah to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, curses are completely different. It's *haram* to curse someone when they don't deserve it. Generally, bearing actual malice toward humans is *haram* when they don't deserve it. So no, you don't need to do something to get your curse to happen.

The Prophet PBUH said: When a curse comes out of one's mouth, it first checks if there's a way  to the one it is directed to (the one deserves it), will go that way, if not, it'll be back to the one who said it.

So it's highly recommended to not say curses about other people. In case you can do nothing else, so you'll say curses and leave it to God. They don't need to be followed by actions like dua's. We do it to avoid taking actions upon anger, and that's the point of curses. When you are hopeless and someone has done many things against you, you leave it to God to give them what they deserve because of their actions and trust God with it.

Comment: Would be nice to have some solid citation to where it's haraam to wish someone malice :)

Comment: There are certainly hadith that I have heard where I believe a sahaba (RA) has been teaching Quran and Islam and has been interrupted and didn't *curse* but made dua for them to be punished, and the person dropped dead on the spot. I can't remember the hadith or if it was even sahih though.

Comment: @Muz: My sources are in my native language. But as for the hadith, if you search you'l find it.

Comment: @Gigili, your response seems nice. Well done. Of course I assume your non-English sources would be profitable as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The word "Cursing" in Arabic means "asking Allah to remove his mercy from this person/thing". So logically, the idea that (Dua'a == cursing) is  wrong. because you can't do anything other than wishing someone to be kicked out from the mercy of Allah.

Now there are 2 types of cursing:

**1**.Cursing the infidels and sinners in general. **it is permissible**

**2**.Cursing a specific or particular person. Scholars have divided into 3 groups:

- Not allowed at all.
- Only infidels but not sinners
- It is permissible

and each of these froups have their own evidence and sources that back up their opinions

---

But Then you look at the hadiths of the prophet Mohammed (PBUH) and what he ask us to be like :

Prophet Mohammed prohibited Muslims to cures,

Ahmad in his Musnad and Imam al-Tirmidhi in his Jaami’ from ‘Alqamah that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) said:

> The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "The believer is not a slanderer, one who curses a great deal, one who indulges in obscenity or who in engages in foul talk."

Al-Tirmidhi said: It is a hasan ghareeb hadeeth.

**2rd hadith,**

> Muslim (2599) narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: It was said: O Messenger of Allaah, pray against the mushrikeen. He said: “I was not sent to curse, rather I was sent as a mercy.”

**3rd Haith,**

> (2597) narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "It is not appropriate for a sincere believer to be given to cursing."

**4th hadith,**

> 2598) narrated that Abu’l-Darda’ (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: "Those who curse a great deal will not be witnesses or intercessors on the Day of Resurrection."

**Now take a note of this hadith**,

it was narrated in al-Saheehayn from Thaabit ibn al-Dahhaak that:

> the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Cursing a believer is like killing him.”

So you are not allowed to curse those who Allah and his prophet's didn't curse in the Quran and the hadith. If you curse anyone other than those mentioned then:

> Narrated by Abu’l-Darda’ (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "When a person curses something, the curse ascends to heaven, and the gates of heaven are closed to it. Then it comes back down to earth and the gates of earth are closed to it. Then it looks right and left, and if it does not find anywhere to go, it goes to the one who was cursed, and if he deserves it (it befalls him), otherwise it goes back to the one who uttered it."

Narrated by Abu Dawood in his Sunan.

Comment: +1 The final hadith has always scared me. Ever since I heard it, I resolved to never curse someone by Allah without thinking a hundred times first.