# Is it harm to curse (i.e., use swearwords)?

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah, punishment, behavior

I curse a lot, because I am surrounded by many teenagers who also curse a lot. Is it haram to curse in Islam? What is the punishment? How can I prevent cursing?

I heard that cursing is a major sin. I want to make sure that true.

Comment: To my assumption, cursing Muslim as well as non-Muslim is not allowed in Islam. Instead you can ask forgiveness and make Dua to show them right path.

Answer (score 4):

At the initial step, I ought to mention that it doesn't justify your negative practice that you said "I curse a lot because i am surrounded by many teenagers who also curse a lot.".

At the second step, as a Briefly speaking, generally cursing (using bad language or word) is considered as a bad act. It would be beneficial for you to pay attention to the verse below of the Holy Quran as a related issue concerning cursing. (Al-An’am: 108):

> وَلَا تَسُبُّوا الَّذِينَ يَدْعُونَ مِن دُونِ اللَّـهِ فَيَسُبُّوا
>   اللَّـهَ عَدْوًا بِغَيْرِ عِلْمٍ ۗ كَذَٰلِكَ زَيَّنَّا لِكُلِّ أُمَّةٍ
>   عَمَلَهُمْ ثُمَّ إِلَىٰ رَبِّهِم مَّرْجِعُهُمْ فَيُنَبِّئُهُم بِمَا
>   كَانُوا يَعْمَلُونَ ﴿١٠٨
>
> And do not insult those they invoke other than Allah, lest they insult
>   Allah in enmity without knowledge. Thus We have made pleasing to every
>   community their deeds. Then to their Lord is their return, and He will
>   inform them about what they used to do. (108)

There is a narration from Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his household) that said:

> **Allah prohibited the Jannah (paradise) for every abuser** (a person that
>   curses) who is shameless-dishonored and doesn’t care what is said to
>   him (her) and wouldn’t be worried and sad.
>
> ان الله حرم الجنه علی کل فحاش بدی قلیل الحیاء لایبال ما قال و لا ما
>   قیل له (کافی، ج۲، ص۳۲۳؛ وسائل، ج۱۱، ص۳۲۹؛ تحف العقول، ص۴۱۶).

Or it has quoted that Prophet Mohammad (pbuh) said:

> Cursing the Moslem is Fsq (debauchery) and Sin.
>
> سِبَابُ الْمُسْلِمِ فُسُوقٌ»؛ شیخ طوسی، محمد بن حسن‏، الأمالی، ص 537،
>   قم، دار الثقافة، چاپ اول، 1414ق؛ شیبانی، أحمد بن محمد، مسند احمد بن
>   حنبل، ج 6، ص 157، بیروت، مؤسسة الرسالة، چاپ اول، 1421ق.

**Conclusion**, you indeed ought to strive not to curse anymore and ask Allah to forgive you. (So, as a famous general Islamic rule, Allah will forgive everyone who repent...)

**Piece of advice**, you can follow the  following verses which suggest that it is better to forgive who make us angry.

> Kind speech and forgiveness are better than charity followed by injury. And Allah is Free of need and Forbearing. (Qur'an 2:263)

and this

> And those who avoid the major sins and immoralities, and when they are angry, they forgive, Qur'an 42:37 (Read [more context](http://quran.com/42/34-40))

---

**References**:

- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/6:108)
- [ahlolbait.blog.ir](http://ahlolbait.blog.ir/1393/03/03/)
- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa33035)

Answer (score 3):

Well at the very first place your behavior is expected I guess.

> O ye who believe! Let not a folk deride a folk who may be better than they (are), not let women (deride) women who may be better than they are; neither defame one another, nor insult one another by nicknames. Bad is the name of lewdness after faith. And whoso turneth not in repentance, such are evil-doers. (Qur'an 49:11)

Next, more detailed answer whether cursing is allowed in Islam or up to which extent it is allowed [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7343/11938) is pretty informative.

In short, some say, cursing a Muslim is not allowed (at any cost) and cursing a disbeliever is OK but not suggested.

The rest as to why is it better to not curse is answered pretty well in [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7343/11938) by Shia_Sunni____________UNIT

> How can I prevent cursing?

Well for that, only one answer is there. And that is **be patient.**

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: To my assumption, cursing Muslim as well as non-Muslim is not allowed in Islam. Instead you can ask forgiveness and make Dua to show them right path.

Comment: We can't ask forgiveness on behalf of disbelievers.

Answer (score -1):

Cursing is definitely a major sin - stay away from it and surround yourself with good people. Just because your friends or classmates curse doesn't mean it's okay. Please, for your sake, try to avoid these kinds of people as they will drag you down the wrong path and perhaps up through the horrifying levels of hell.

May Allah guide us all to the straight path.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Dear brother or sister, 
Cursing is a sin. Please for your sake, stop and just ask for forgiveness. Don’t be friends with these type of people. They will eventually lead you to hell. Allah the almighty will forgive you. Trust me.