# Tie the camel hadith

Tags: hadith-interpretation, tawakkul

[Source](https://jscherfi.com/2017/04/15/tie-your-camel/)

> *Anas ibn Malik reported: A man said, “O Messenger of Allah, should I tie my camel and trust in Allah, or should I leave her untied and trust in Allah?” The Messenger of Allah, peace, and blessings be upon him, said, “Tie her and trust in Allah.”*
>
> *2nd Source: [Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2517](https://sunnah.com/urn/727020)*

Okay, I have several questions regarding this Hadith:

1. If I tie my camel well, why should I rely on Allah? What am I expecting him to do?
2. Suppose, I tie my camel well and rely on Allah, and still, the camel is lost for some reason (because of, like, theft, natural calamity, and so forth) what would that mean?

Regardless of my reliance on Allah, there is a 50% chance that I may lose my camel.

So, a more relevant question is, why should I even bother to think about a possible scenario with so much complexity? Why not just tie my camel and if the camel is lost for some reason, just don't bother?

Comment: This is a relevant post: [Are du'as without action accepted by Allah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/are-duas-without-action-accepted-by-allah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of trusting Allah like buying insurance. There are many benefits to buying this insurance and this is a list of the possible benefits:

- You are doing a good deed by trusting Allah and gain reward for that trust.
- Involving Allah in your task (i.e. tying the camel) makes the task itself into a good deed and you will gain reward for that.
- Allah will protect the camel from any number of possible of unknowable disasters/problems that might happen.
- In the case that he chooses not to, it will be for your own worldly benefit somehow.
- In case there is no worldly benefit, Allah has decided to forgive your sins through the difficulty.

On the other hand, if you just tie the camel you don't have any of the above benefits.

Answer (score 3):

**On tawakkul**

First of all having trust or confidence in Allah is one of the major and essential parts of monotheism.

As this means that you do a thing and believe that it is in the hands of Allah to cause or bring any benefit and throw away any bear.

Allah the almighty says:

> ... **And whoever relies upon Allah - then He is sufficient for him**. Indeed, Allah will accomplish His purpose. Allah has already set for everything a [decreed] extent. ([65:3](https://legacy.quran.com/65/3))

Therefore the prophet () has taught ibn 'Abbas saying:

> 'O boy! I will teach you a statement: Be mindful of Allah and He will protect you. Be mindful of Allah and you will find Him before you. When you ask, ask Allah, and when you seek aid, seek Allah's aid. Know that if the entire creation were to gather together to do something to benefit you- you would never get any benefit except that Allah had written for you. And if they were to gather to do something to harm you- you would never be harmed except that Allah had written for you. The pens are lifted and the pages are dried.'
>   ([Jami' at-Tirmdihi](https://sunnah.com/urn/727010) and according to ibn Kathir also in Musnad Ahmad -see in [here](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1317&Itemid=121) qtafsir-)

Many verses of the qur'an show the basis of tawakkul (trust and reliance in Allah) for example repeat every day at least seventeen times:

> It is You we worship and **You we ask for help**. ([1:5](https://legacy.quran.com/1/5))

It is an attribute of the true believers:

- > ... and upon Allah the believers should rely. ([3:122](https://legacy.quran.com/3/122))
- > The believers are only those who, when Allah is mentioned, their hearts become fearful, and when His verses are recited to them, it increases them in faith; and upon their Lord they rely - ([8:2](https://legacy.quran.com/8/2))
- > ... But what is with Allah is better and more lasting for those who have believed and upon their Lord rely ([42:36](https://legacy.quran.com/42/36))

And Allah reminds us:

> ... so worship Him and **rely upon Him**. ... ([11:123](https://legacy.quran.com/11/123))

**On the interpretation of "tie it and trust in Allah"**

In his tohfat al-Awhwadhi [تحفة الأحوذي](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=56&ID=4819) al-Mubrakpuri محمد بن عبد الرحمن بن عبد الرحيم المباركفوري when commenting on this hadith said:
<sub>In the following I will translate from Arabic, as it is my own translation take it carefully</sub>

> ( قال اعقلها ) قال المناوي  : أي شد ركبة ناقتك مع ذراعيها بحبل ( وتوكل ) أي اعتمد على الله ، وذلك لأن عقلها لا ينافي التوكل
>    (He said: "Tie it) means tie the knee with the cubit with a rope (and trust in Allah)  means rely on Allah, this is because tying the camel is not opposed to tawakkul (trust in Allah).

**On tawakkul and taking means and measures**

Trust in Allah doesn't mean that we have to leave things to Allah without taking means and measures. The prophets () are good examples when it comes to trust in Allah nevertheless they also taught us to take means and measures Nuh () built the ark, Yusuf () didn't tell his dream to his brothers, they followed the instruction of their father not to enter from the same door ... Allah says:

> ... And when you have decided, then rely upon Allah . Indeed, Allah loves those who rely [upon Him]. ([3:159](https://legacy.quran.com/3/159))

So we may take a decision, make a plan take means and measures and then trust in Allah and do whatever we have planed before.

Allah also say:

- > **O you who have believed, take your precaution** and [either] go forth in companies or go forth all together. ([4:71](https://legacy.quran.com/4/71))
- > **And prepare against them whatever you are able of power** and of steeds of war  ... ([8:60](https://legacy.quran.com/8/60))

which generally means be prepared. And if our taken means and measures are not sufficient we are taught that Allah is helping his true believers:

> And when the two companies saw one another, the companions of Moses said, "Indeed, we are to be overtaken!" (61) [Moses] said, "No! Indeed, with me is my Lord; He will guide me." (62) ([26:61-62](https://legacy.quran.com/26/61-62))

and we know how the story ended.

As good believers we may also remind ourselves verses such as:

- > ... But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not. ([2:216](https://legacy.quran.com/2/216))
- > And you do not will except that Allah wills - Lord of the worlds. ([81:29](https://legacy.quran.com/81/29))

I intended this as a <s>short</s> addition to the good answer of @TheZ.

As for the guidelines of taking means and measures red the fatwa islamqa #[213652](https://islamqa.info/en/213652)

Comment: Excellent answer.  May God reward you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have no idea what trust in Allah (Tawakkul )means,it means you believe that everything happens (both bad and good) according to God’s plan, and you should rely on him not on camel,
The benefit of Tawakkul is not that you will not loose the camel but gives you a state of mind that  it doesn’t matter even if camel is gone

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a scholar but as per my understanding this means you need to take care of your things. For example if you do not tie your camel what will happen to your camel? Obviously you may lose it. So without securing your camel don't expect an angel will fly and save your camel!! But if you take care of your camel it wouldn't run away. So now coming to your point that what you are expecting Allah to do if you already secured your camel? Well now when you have done your job then totally rely on Allah for whatever will happen will be the will of Allah.  May be your camel die, still runs away, stolen or something happens or may be your camel still sitting there calmly, is all the will of Allah. And whatever happens is a test and is for full of goodness with or without your knowledge. So trust in Allah but do your job first. This covers your second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thawakkul is the belief that “if Allah intents good or HARM for you no one can prevent that”
Therefore even if you lost your camel ,your thawwakkul is unchallenged 
What thawakkul does is it put your mind at rest “that Allah intended that camel for me it will be there otherwise it will be lost “
And if it is lost you can console yourself that it is Allah’s decision